# Postgres /root": Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, unix, postgresql

why on ubuntu 14.10 every time that i try to start the postgres on:

```
sudo -p 'sudo password: ' -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/initdb -D /mnt/postgresql/9.4/data
```

show this:

> could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied The files
>   belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
>   This user must also own the server process.
>
> initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment
>   variables

Comment: x-posted http://stackoverflow.com/q/32323090/398670

Comment: yeah, another guy recommended to post this type of question here

Comment: No problem. I'm just cross-linking so if someone finds one they can see there might be more info at the other.

Answer (score 1):

There are three parts in the output:

1. **could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied**: your 'sudo' succeeds but your postgres user fails to access the home of root. You may check for the setting of homedirectory for postgres in /etc/passwd.
2. **The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres". This user must also own the server process.** : This is the normal permissions reminder from initdb. So you know initdb started regardles of failed directory change.
3. **initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables**: here initdb fails for real due to missing locale settings.

I think You need to check your sudo configuration and make sure your postgres user has a proper environment before calling initdb.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

```
stat -c "%G" .
```

### Step 2

```
sudo usermod -aG <the output from the step 1> postgres
```

[df.tips/t/2063/2](https://df.tips/t/2063/2)